# VUE como traer un archivo.vue a mi template

Tags: vue.js

Estoy empezando con VUE y no logro entender como hacer que desde un archivo que se llama modales.vue donde están mi modale lograr traerlo a mi componente en la parte del template de mi index.js.

Podría hacerlo de manera literal con las `` pero queda muy poco comprensible.
es posible hacer esto de esta manera que intento o no es no conozco mucho de vue por tanto no se si es correcto.

Este es el archivo index.js

```js
Vue.component('mi-compo',{
 template: `<p>como traigo el archivo modales.vue donde esta el modal que necesito</p>`,                    
    data(){
     return{
      unidad:'',
     };
    },
    methods:{
     close: function () {
      this.$emit('close');
        this.unidad = '';
        this.dialog = false;
     }
    }
});

new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data () {
    return {
      tab: null,
      text1: 'Lorem ipsum dolorconsequat.',
      text2:'CREA TU SOLICITUD',
      icons: false,
      }
  },
});
```

```js
aqui el arvhivo modales.vue
<template>
 <v-row justify="center">
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">CREAR NUEVA SRM</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="headline">DATOS SRM</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <v-select
                    v-model="unidad"
                      :items="['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']"
                      label="Unidad*"
                      required
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-col>
          
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close()">Close</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

Comment: Estas usando webpack?

Comment: @RimuruTempest solo vue y vuetify

Comment: Cuando registras un componente de la manera como lo muestras, éste queda disponible en el scope global, así que en la plantilla de otro componente bastaría poner `<mi-compo></mi-compo>`.  Puedes tener cada cosa en archivos separados, sólo preocúpate de cargar vue.js y vuetify antes que el resto. Y cuando estés cómodo, puedes usar importación de módulos ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes haces es importa el archivo .vue a tu código js, de esta forma:

*modales.vue*

```html
<template>
    <v-row justify="center">
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" persistent max-width="600px">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark v-on="on">CREAR NUEVA SRM</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="headline">DATOS SRM</span>
            </v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="6">
                    <v-select
                    v-model="unidad"
                      :items="['B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'B4']"
                      label="Unidad*"
                      required
                    ></v-select>
                  </v-col>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close()">Close</v-btn>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="dialog = false">Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

```
import modales from 'modales.vue'
Vue.component('mi-compo',{
    template: modales,                    
    data(){
        return{
            unidad:'',
        };
    },
    methods:{
        close: function () {
            this.$emit('close');
            this.unidad = '';
            this.dialog = false;
        }
    }
});

new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    vuetify: new Vuetify(),
    data () {
    return {
      tab: null,
      text1: 'Lorem ipsum dolorconsequat.',
      text2:'CREA TU SOLICITUD',
      icons: false,
      }
  },
});
```

Comment: estoy algo perdido esto debe estar en el archivo index.js o en el .vue, mi ignorancia, si cambio la etiqueta template por la <script type="text/x-template" id="mi-compo"> el texto html queda todo en blanco y me es muy dificil de leer porque no queda con los highlighting de html , Me faltara algun import o export

Comment: @jonathan también puedes importar el archivo `modales.vue`, así como edite mi respuesta